# Converting RGB to Lab using skimage.color.rgb2lab

Tags: python, image-processing, colors, scipy, scikit-image

I have a strange observation when converting RGB pixel values to Lab space.

Let's take the following reference values in RGB.

```
import skimage
colors = {'red': np.array((255, 0, 0)), 'orange': np.array((255, 69, 0)),
           'yellow': np.array((255, 255, 0)), 'green': np.array((0, 128, 0)),
           'blue': np.array((0, 0, 255)), 'white': np.array((255, 255, 255)), 
           'black': np.array((0, 0, 0)), 'brown': np.array((139, 69, 19)), 
           'gray': np.array((128, 128, 128))}
```

Now I'm converting them to lab color space using `skimage.color.rgb2lab`:

```
colors_lab = {key: skimage.color.rgb2lab(np.array(np.ones((1, 1, 3)) * value, dtype=int)) for (key, value) in colors.items()}
print(colors_lab)

"""
{'red': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
 'orange': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
 'yellow': array([[[ 3.55271368e-15, 1.38777878e-14,  5.55111512e-15]]]),
 'green': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
 'blue': array([[[ 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, -5.55111512e-15]]]),
 'white': array([[[3.55271368e-15, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00]]]),
 'black': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
 'brown': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
 'gray': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]])}
"""
```

I think I'm missing something here. Red, Orange, Green, Black, Brown, and Gray shouldn't have the same value `[0, 0, 0]`.

What am I missing here?

---

## Answer:

As suggested by @MarkSetchell, the function [`rgb2lab`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2lab) expects the RGB array to have elements in the range 0 to 1. (This is not mentioned in the documentation) i.e.,

```
colors_lab = {key: skimage.color.rgb2lab(np.array(np.ones((1, 1, 3)) * value/255)) for (key, value) in colors.items()}
print(colors_lab)

"""
{'black': array([[[0., 0., 0.]]]),
'blue': array([[[  32.29567257,   79.18559091, -107.85730021]]]),
'brown': array([[[37.46978642, 26.44214425, 40.98418759]]]),
'gray': array([[[ 5.35850135e+01, -1.47264555e-03,  2.79145150e-03]]]),
'green': array([[[ 46.2276577 , -51.69868348,  49.89707556]]]),
'orange': array([[[57.58158901, 67.7824008 , 68.95825825]]]),
'red': array([[[53.24058794, 80.09230823, 67.20275104]]]),
'white': array([[[ 1.00000000e+02, -2.45493786e-03,  4.65342115e-03]]]),
 'yellow': array([[[ 97.13950704, -21.55468102,  94.47812228]]])}"""
```

---

Comment: Your `dtype=int` is messing you up. Try `skimage.color.rgb2lab(np.ones((1,1,3))*[0,0,255])`

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've tried that. IIRC it returned an array that has elements in orders of thousands (way beyond the range of lab space) so I've guessed that the function expects `int`. Let me add it to question.

Comment: Ok, try scaling your RGB to range 0..1, i.e. `skimage.color.rgb2lab(np.ones((1,1,3))*[0,0,1.0]) ` for blue.

Comment: @MarkSetchell there we go! The [Docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2lab) do not mention that. Thanks!

Comment: @MarkSetchell please write an answer mentioning this. I'll see if I can contribute to improve the docs.

Comment: It's ok. Go ahead and write it up and edit in any pull requests or changes you suggest, then you can accept it and grab the points.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've edited the question to include the answer. Thanks for the nice find!

Comment: @akilat90 This is mentioned in the docs here: https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/user_guide/data_types.html

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt Thanks! As a relatively new user for skimage, I've suspected that there must be something to do with `dtype` (hence `dtype=int` in my question) but the link you've mentioned wasn't easy to find. I think a pointer to this in the docstring might help. I'm happy to contribute if you think this is needed.

Comment: Yes, we're working toward not leaning on dtypes so much to know ranges, but unfortunately it's needed sometimes.  Any suggestions on a good place to surface this, that doesn't requiring peppering the entire codebase with links to this document would be welcome.  Please join us on our Zulip chat or the mailing list, or file a GitHub issue—whatever is most convenient for you.

Comment: Not sure if this is still relevant, but when I pass an RGB image loaded as a numpy array, which has values between ~0, 255~ it converts it correctly. But when I pass in an array of rgb values that is not an image say of shape (1,5,3) (a color palette for example), I need to manually scale the values between (0, 1) to get a correct conversion.

Comment: @AhmadMoussa I guess that has something to do with `dtype` if your array. IIRC, the documentation mentions about the significance of dtypes.